# Not able to login mysql -uroot -proot using vagrant

Tags: mysql, vagrant

```
mysql -uroot -proot
```

This is the error I get:

> mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be
>   insecure. ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Can you connect to the mysql through some other method to check the setup?  There are some subtleties to setting up Grant Tables.  All possible problems, however, yield the same error (so an attacker gets no info).  You'll need some way to access the mysql that grants you access to the Grant Table in order to fix it.  And seeing what's there will help figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution of the problem i was facing:

The hosts file on local has no edit permission and that's why on setting up the vagrant i.e vagrant up the vagrant ip from config.yml/ default.config.yml file was not being copied to local hosts file.

So i did:
 1. Go  outside vagrant. 
 2. sudo vim /etc/hosts
 3. Copy the vagrant_ip of config.yml/default.config.yml file present for your particular project.
 4. edit the hosts file and add ip address and alias url of the project.

That's all we are done.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends of your 'image'.
If you are connecting via SSH you can also try to login without a password

```
mysql -u root
```

I am using scotch-box vagrant image and works for me (note that the connections made by my php scripts requires the root user password).

Comment: This is what happening:
vagrant@my_project:/var/www/my_project/drupal$ mysql -uroot -proot
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

Comment: Have you tried to enter the password later ?

    mysql -u root -p (then enter) mysql should ask for a password

Answer (score -1):

Try using the wamp server to connect to mysql.

Comment: Why do you assume the use of Wamp?

Comment: Wamp gives the user an easy way to access the root or rather an easy login.